# Dataverse Filter option missing

Tags: power-platform, dataverse

I am a bit lost with dataverse table. The last time I checked, I saw a filter that allows me to filter and show only custom columns. I checked today but it is gone. Are there any changes in design that Microsoft has hidden or any configuration changes?

See below image for the reference:
[image]

Please do the needful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is missing/have been removed.
Alternatively you can filter on column "Name" to filter all custom columns.

Example in my case , Filter applied on "Name" column to get all columns starting from cr787_
It is displaying all custom columns other than "Name" column.